# iPhone SDK: Problem with textFieldDidEndEditing being called

Tags: iphone

In our app, in some cases, textFieldDidEndEditing is not being fired. After some debugging, it was easy to see the reason why....textFieldShouldEndEditing was returning NO when the current field is deemed invalid or in other words returning no from textFieldShouldEndEditing.

In the normal case, this behavior works just fine. However, if the user tries to cancel out of the form all together without every fixing the data problem flagged in textFieldShouldEndEditing, some critical code in textFieldDidEndEditing is never being called because that event never fires if textFieldShouldEndEditing=NO;

Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to deal with this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do an [yorTextField resignFirstResponder]; when user try to cancel.

Comment: this seems to work....setting an instance variable when the user presses cancel and then using that in textFieldShouldEndEditing ie. = YES;

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work....setting an instance variable when the user presses cancel and then using that in textFieldShouldEndEditing ie. = YES